# How can I be sure a jQuery UI dialog has been totally destroyed?

Tags: javascript, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog in a backbone view and I want to check if the dialog is destroyed after this code is executed:

```
this.$el.dialog('destroy').remove();
```

Is it possible to do this check easily? I am not seeing any backbone method for this.

Comment: This is unrelated to Backbone since it's using jquery-ui-dialog and jQuery related functions. What are you trying to solve? Are there zombie events you want gone?